# Can I auto-format the opening bracket on the same line with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there possible to auto-format in Visual Studio like this

```
public int Id {
    get => id; 
}
```

rather than

```
public int Id 
{
    get => id; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup,

Go to Tools -> Options

and find

TextEditor -> Your language -> Code Style -> Formatting -> New Lines

Unselect the options for when you do not want new lines.

All languages don't have this option but I guess you are looking for C#.